# Image Processing: Algorithm to detect SnapCodes?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scannable-code

I am currently working on a project using Python to detect Snapcodes among a set a pictures. For those who don't know what a Snapcode is, [here are some examples](https://www.google.fr/search?q=snapcodes&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja_5fS1ZPMAhWFlSwKHVwoDhAQ_AUIBygB&biw=1280&bih=705#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=snapchat+codes).

I am looking for the most simple solution to perform this detection using the Python language.

Comment: Are they pictures of the codes taken with a camera? Or are they images with codes in them?

Comment: No they are screenshot of a Snapcode exactly like that http://cdn0.dailydot.com/uploaded/images/original/2015/7/1/snapchat-qr-selfie.jpg and they are among a set of photographies pictures. Thanks Blender.

Comment: Then all you need to do is find roughly-square yellow blobs in the image and filter them out based on the presence of dots.

Comment: Well, the location may differ because of the size of the screen. Moreover sometimes screenshot are cropped. So your solution may not work. Thanks :)

Comment: As in the actual code is partially obstructed?

Comment: Yes, the snapcodes screenshots may vary, but the snapcode is not obstructed.

Comment: So just do yellow blob detection, find the ones with the right shape, and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi Matt.  How did this go?  I'm trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an image classification algorithm like svm to find the Snap codes from a given set of images.In the case of svm you first need to train svm using some pictures of snap codes and some other non-snap code pics.Once training phase completed you can predict whether given image is a snapcode or not.SVM is already implemented in Opencv.

[Usefull stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250087/what-it-mean-by-training-svm)

[what is svm with code-but in java](http://makematics.com/code/psvm/)

[opencv implementation of image classifier using svm with python code](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d3b/tutorial_py_svm_opencv.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any link or tutorial I should read?